# Netbeans Check Regular Expression

Tags: java, netbeans-12

Here is an example of a very simple method.  We take "foo bar", split, replaceAll, and print.

```
public static void main(String[] args){
  String string="foo bar";
  String[] array=string.split(" ");
  String string2=string.replaceAll(".* ","");
  System.out.println(array[0]);
  System.out.println(string2);
}
```

NetBeans is claiming this is a problem and giving me a warning on `split` and `replaceAll`.

[image]

I can't seem to find a way to disable this via @annotation, and information about this issue is sparse on the 'net. What is the intended effect of this warning?

Comment: The warnings seem intended to let you know that the regex patterns may have some problem.  This would be especially true in the second of `.* `, where the space after `.*` doesn't make any sense.

Comment: The space is required.  this example prints `foo` on the first line and `bar` on the second.  Without the space there is no delimiter.

Comment: Similar regular expressions of `string.split("\\s")` and `string.replaceAll(".*\\s", "")` provide the same warning.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen It's counter intuitive, but I'm not sure that the warnings are there to let you know that there is a _problem_ with your regular expressions at all. Instead I think they serve to highlight the _mere existence_ of regular expressions in your source code, though there is more to it than that. See my answer for clarification.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The feature "Check Regular Expression" was recently implemented in NetBeans 12.5.

It is formally documented in Apache NetBeans issue [NETBEANS-5661 Testing for valid values of a Regular Expression in the IDE](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NETBEANS-5661) which has the **Description** "*Adding a feature for testing the valid values for a Regular Expression in the IDE itself*".

It is also mentioned in the [Release Notes for NetBeans 12.5](https://netbeans.apache.org/download/nb125/index.html):

> [NETBEANS-5661] - Added regular expression window and hint:
> https://github.com/apache/netbeans/pull/2953

In the **Attachments** section of NetBeans Issue 5661 there is a link named [RegexDemo2.gif](https://issues.apache.org/jira/secure/attachment/13025011/RegexDemo2.gif) which gives a demo of the new functionality. It allows you to test regular expressions within your Java source, in a **Check Regular Expressions** window.

To configure your preference for this feature, navigate to **Tools > Options > Editor > Hints**, then select *Java* from the **Language** drop list. As shown in the screen shot below, you can then:

- Turn the feature off completely, by unchecking the *Check Regular Expression* entry.
- Alternatively, generate an *Error*, *Warning*, or *Warning on Current Line* by selecting the appropriate **Show As** entry.

  [image: Options window]

You can also navigate to that configuration screen directly from the relevant line in your code using tooltips:

[image: tooltips]

For trivial regular expressions (as in your sample code) this new feature may be a minor irritation, in which case turn it off. But for code which contains many regular expressions, or some complex regular expressions, I think this feature could be useful and productive. You might perhaps generate the warnings during development and for code reviews, but then turn it off prior to final deployment.

One final point: those warning/error messages do not necessarily imply that there is anything *wrong* with your regular expression at all. Instead, the feature serves to highlight the *existence* of regular expressions in your code, and provides a means to easily *test* them.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation!  Great answer! Shouldn't that be a "Warning on current line" rather than a generic warning?   When performing quick checks on code, that yellow indicator at the top right of the window is a good quick check and this invalidates the usefulness of that top right box.

Comment: @AdamOutler Sure - whatever you prefer, since there is no right/wrong answer. I was just posting a screen shot to show the available options, and didn't mean to imply any specific preference. That said, I would probably use the generic _Warning_ to blindly capture the use of all regexes until the code had passed review, and then disable the feature for deployment. As an aside, I'm not sure why selecting the option _Error_ would be helpful. Any ideas?